# radio buttons displaying incorrectly

Tags: iphone, html, css, ipad, radio-button

I have a few radio buttons that are displayed like regular buttons, they look like this:

```
            <div class="buttoncontainer" style="position:relative; left: 80px;">
                <label><input type="radio" name="toggle" checked="checked" class="_today">          <span class="css3button-left">Today</span></label>
                <label><input type="radio" name="toggle" class="_tomorrow"><span class="css3button">Tomorrow</span></label>
                <label><input type="radio" name="toggle" class="_weekend"><span class="css3button">This Weekend</span></label>
                <label><input type="radio" name="toggle" class="_nextmonth"><span class="css3button-right">Next Month</span></label>
            </div>
```

I change the buttons appearance when selected like this:

```
     .buttoncontainer  input:checked + span
     { 
        ...
     }
```

This works in every browser I tested - IE, FireFox, Chrome, and even Safari on my computer , but the appearance will never change to :checked on the Ipad or Iphone using Safari .  Does any one have any idea why these buttons don't work only on ipad ?

Comment: Can you show us what you want it to look like and what it is looking like

Comment: I just want :checked to fire to change the appearance , I can post all the css if you want

Comment: Please show us screenshots of what it looks like in the browser vs what it looks like on the phone.

Comment: I'll get one posted , it will just take a little bit to post from ipad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you mean that the lables are not clickable?

For some reasons the usual behaviour of the `label` element does not work on the mobile WebKit out of the box.

Adding `label { cursor: pointer; }` to the CSS fixes the issue.

Comment: no , they are clickable , and they work , the problem is the css doesn't change to the :checked version of the CSS

Comment: @ScottSelby hm strange, that was the issue I ran into when trying out your snippet (the `:checked + span` styles were applied correctly). You should probably add the CSS and some screenshots like statet in the comments to your question.

Comment: It works fine in every browser I tried it in except on a IPad